# XPath indexes of nodes

Tags: java, javascript, xslt, xpath

I am dealing with very primitive HTML construction that goes like this:

```
<a NAME="header1"></a><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000"><font size=+1>Hygiene</font></font></font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000">Shampoo</font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000"></font>Soap</font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000">Deodorant</font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000">Toothpaste</font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000"></font>Brush</font></b> 

<a NAME="header2"></a><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000"><font size=+1>Food</font></font></font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000">Meat</font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000">Vegetables</font></b> 
    <p><b><font face="Verdana, Serif"><font color="#000000">Fruit</font></b>
```

The thing is now, I want to get all items from Hygiene header (top) which are Shampoo, Soap, Deodorant, Toothpaste, Brush (and put them in let's say HashMap> for now).

I use this XPath to get the headers (Hygiene and Food):

```
//html/body//b/font/font/font
```

And it works fine, I get what I need.

Then I use this XPath to collect the items:

```
//html/body//p/b/font/font
```

for ALL items. So this (last) XPath would return a list from all items which are [Shampoo, Soap, Deodorant, Toothpaste, Brush, Meat, Vegetables, Fruit]. The thing is that I don't know when to stop putting items in the first list (like, when another header starts, which is Food in this case, create new list and put the Food items there). All I can get with this XPaths is the values of the headers (Hygiene, Food) and ALL items from both lists (not separate).

I need to get something like:

- Map{"Hygiene", [Shampoo, Soap, Deodorant, Toothpaste, Brush]}
- Map{"Food", [Meat, Vegetables, Fruit]}

All items are thrown like this and they are not in separate divs or spans so that I can recognize when new header had cometh.

Thanks!

Comment: You 're going to have a hard time because that's crap input. Are you **totally sure** that's what it looks like (e.g. product names *outside* the `<font color>` tags)? Because details like that are going to make all the difference.

Comment: yes you are right, I updated the html. The Item is in the <font> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to parse this HTML because it's not amenable to parsing (judging from the `<font>` tags you could probably use some colorful language about it as well).

AFAIK there's no way to express a "following siblings until X" condition in XPath, so here's an alternative: use *one* XPath expression that matches both headers and items, for example with this specific markup you could use

```
//body//font/child::text()
```

which will select all text nodes ("Hygiene", "Shampoo", "Soap", ...).

The nodes will be returned in document order (this is *extremely important*), so afterwards you can iterate over the results and perform a test on each to determine if it's a header or an item (in this case you could check if the parent is a `<font>` element that has a `size` attribute).

This way you can keep a reference to the last "header" found and add all following "items" to an appropriate data structure under it until you come across the next header, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by (a) converting this to XML using (say) TagSoup, then (b) using an XSLT 2.0 transformation that up-converts this to a more sanitary XML structure.

I'm not sure exactly what TagSoup would make of it, but if we assume that the only thing it does is to close the p tags (with the `</p>` appearing after the `</b>`), then step (b) is quite simple:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//body/*" group-starting-with="a">
  <section name="current-group()[self::b]">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[self::p]">
       <item><xsl:value-of select="."/></item>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </section>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This will give you something like

```
<section name="Hygiene">
  <item>Shampoo</item>
  <item>Soap</item>
  <item>Toothpaste</item>
</section>
<section name="Food">
  <item>Meat</item>
  <item>Veg</item>
</section>
```

which is then much easier to play with.

Generally when you've got poorly structured input like this, it's best to use a pipeline approach where you first clean it up, then query it to get the information you want.